# Tor Browser doesn't work on Win10 after update

Tags: firefox, network-configuration

So I'm trying to open Tor Browser but it's just doesn't open and shows me this empty message box:

[image: Screenshot of empty Error Message]

I've done some research and found some solution with windows firewall but it didn't help at all:

[image: Cropped screenshot of firewall display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update everything fixed so it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

So for some interesting reasons that I absolutely don't understand my Tor Browser only opens through RightClick_on_shortcut -> Start Tor Browser but not through just double click on desktop shortcut. That's weird because that feature stays even after reinstall. I even checked the path to exe and it's the same on both desktop shortcut and it's button.